# how can I change my Facebook account on a app game or how to fix that error?

Tags: default-applications

I am trying to change an account on a app I've downloaded (heart of Vegas slot game) I use to be able to change it before but now everytime I try to log into my Facebook account it won't let me.. It always pops up a warning sign saying ERROR  " you have already logged into one Facebook account on this device . please use same account to continue" I've already tried to uninstall the app and reinstall it, I also tried to clear cache, and also tried to clear data but none is working..

HELP!?

Comment: Ever figure it out? I have the same problem.